# Изменение кнопки В корзину после нажатии на удалить товар с корзины woocommerce wordpress

Tags: wordpress

Ниже рабочий код но при обновлении страницы если нажать кнопку еще раз он опять 1 товар добавить в корзину как блокировать кнопку и изменить текст на товар уже в корзине или удалить товар с корзины, тут еще нужно сделать ajax чтобы не обновлять стр каждый раз

// Change the add to cart text on single product pages
add_filter('woocommerce_product_single_add_to_cart_text', 'woo_custom_cart_button_text');
function woo_custom_cart_button_text() {

```
foreach( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $values ) {
    $_product = $values['data'];

    if( get_the_ID() == $_product->get_ID() ) {
        return __('Already in cart - Add Again?', 'woocommerce');
    }
}

return __('Add to cart', 'woocommerce');
```

}

// Change the add to cart text on product archives
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_add_to_cart_text', 'woo_archive_custom_cart_button_text' );
function woo_archive_custom_cart_button_text() {

```
foreach( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $values ) {
    $_product = $values['data'];

    if( get_the_ID() == $_product->get_ID() ) {
        return __('Already in cart', 'woocommerce');
    }
}

return __('Add to cart', 'woocommerce');
```

}

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask и https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/6688/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81-%D0%BF%D0%BE-wordpress